# SmoothScrollToPositionWithOffset это реально?

Tags: android, recyclerview, прокрутка, layoutmanager

Можно ли плавно(!) передвинуть RecyclerView на позицию N с заданным отклонением вверх/вниз?

Тут конечно приходят на помощь методы `SmoothScrollBy()` или `LayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset()`, но эти методы либо не имеют анимации, либо свою скорость прокрутки нельзя установить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

как вариант - написать свой класс, дочерний к лайаут менеджеру, который внутри себя использует `SmoothScroller`

пример [тут](https://mcochin.wordpress.com/2015/05/13/android-customizing-smoothscroller-for-the-recyclerview/)